# Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined? why this error is coming?

Tags: javascript

```js
var select = document.getElementById("source"); 
var select2= document.getElementById("status");
var option = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5","6","7","8","9"];
var option2= [];

function moveright() {
    var a = source.options[source.selectedIndex].value;
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = a;
    select2.add(option);
    select.remove(i);
}

function moveleft() {
    var b = status.option2[status.selectedIndex].value;
    var option2 = document.createElement("option");
    option2.text = b;
    select.add(option2);
    select2.remove(i);
}

for(i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
    var opt = option[i];
    var a = document.createElement("option");
    a.innerHTML = opt;
    a.value = opt;
    select.appendChild(a);
}

for(i = 0; i < option2.length; i++) {
    var opt2 = option2[i];
    var a = document.createElement("option");
    a.innerHTML = opt2;
    a.value = opt2;
    select2.appendChild(a);
}
```

```html
<select id = "source" multiple size = "10" onclick = "moveright ()">
    <option>Choose a number</option>
</select>
<select id = "status" multiple size = "10" onclick = "moveleft ()">
    <option>Choose a number </option>
</select>
```

I am new to JavaScript I am trying to push the drop down values from one drop down to another. First drop down is working, but second drop down is not working. Can anyone help me? I tried only in the JavaScript array.

Comment: `var select = (select element)` ... `var a = source.options[source.selectedIndex]` - see the problem here? `source.options` is undefined. `source.selectedIndex` is undefined. You're trying to get the property `undefined` of `undefined`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly changed, but giving you expected results ;)
Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/30gu88xf/2/)

In your `moveright` and `moveright` you had a variable `i` which was not defined. I assume you wanted to use selected option index to remove itself.

And you should write full selector for getting elements, not using it's id directly. Browser picked up `source` id and returned as html element, however it could not do that with `status`, because there is such property as [`window.status`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp).

Comment: Thanks,  a lot @Mantas Čekanauskas

Comment: Good to hear ;)